# Replace entity model property with value from database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an entity framework object model with two entities:

```
Alert (1-*) ----- (1) Check
```

The `Check` table has a unique constraint on the column `UniqueProperty`.

Checks are usually pre-existing entities in my database and any new alert should be added to existing checks.

I create a simple object graph somewhere in my code:

```
var alert = new Alert();
alert.Check = new Check { UniqueProperty = someValue };
```

Sometime later I'd like to persist my object graph:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.Alerts.AddObject(alert);

  // Replace temp check with actual database check if available.
  var checkFromDb = context.Checks.SingleOrDefault(
      c => c.UniqueProperty = alert.Check.UniqueProperty);
  if (checkFromDb != null)
  {
    alert.Check = checkFromDb;
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, when there is a corresponding check in the database, use that one, otherwise do nothing (and it will simply be added).

The code above causes a unique constraint violation on the `UniqueProperty` constraint. The reason is that EF remembers the first check, even though I replace it later with the check from the database.

How can I get rid of that first check?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set up the check until you're ready to save.  If one already exists, add the alert to the existing check's alerts collection.  If it doesn't, create a new one associate with the check, then add the alert to the db.

```
var alert = new Alert();

...

using (var context = new MyContext())
{

  // Replace temp check with actual database check if available.
  var checkFromDb = context.Checks.SingleOrDefault(
      c => c.UniqueProperty = alert.Check.UniqueProperty);
  if (checkFromDb != null)
  {
    checkFromDb.Alerts.Add( alert );
  }
  else
  {
    alert.Check = new Check { UniqueProperty = some value };
    context.Alerts.AddObject(alert);
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hm, this will definitely solve the issue but I need the `Check` in the `Alert` from the beginning. The object graph I create is the object model for a wizard that may take several minutes to complete. Only at the end can I save the entire graph.

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg, then the only thing I can suggest is that you get it at the beginning if it exists.

Comment: This could also be a problem because the app is multi-user. The checks that exist at the point where one wizard starts may not be the same checks that exist when the wizard ends because another user may have caused more checks to be created...

Comment: I was experimenting with ObjectStateManager and RelationshipManager but everything I tried only caused other exceptions.

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg then don't carry an entity model all the way through the wizard.  Use a view/wizard model to hold the data, then create the entity at the final step. That is, "pretend" that the wizard completes in one step as far as the database is concerned. This may mean that your logic needs to be able to back up in the wizard.

Comment: That would also be a solution, albeit one that would take me a lot of time. Of course the object graph is way more complex then just `Alert` and `Check` :)